# Elasticsearch query design via RESTful API

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a query that first lets me get a list of followers that are following a user, second it should take that list and then check to see if they are 'online'.

I have two 'indexes' or endpoints /channel and /following.

The channel endpoint JSON object looks like this (parts abbreviated)

```
{ channel: {"username":"username1", ... , "online":"true" } }
```

The following endpoint object looks a bit like this

```
{ following : {"username1":{"username2":"username2", "username3":"username3"} }
```

if I run a simple query /following/_search I get back hits like...

```
{
   "_index": "following",
   "_type": "following",
   "_id": "_Liso_",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
   "Gabe": "Gabe",
      "Gavin": "Gavin"
   }
}
```

This result means that Gavin is following Gabe.

I believe the issue is how I'm storing the data.
In firebase my data looks like this

```
following
  |---Gabe
        |----Gavin:Gavin
```

so each child object of following object has key/value children of {username}:{username}

Now I can run queries that individually get the results I need. For example, if I ask ElasticSearch (ES) if channel "Gavin" is "online" I get back one result depending on if they are or are not online.  And same with Following.  However I can't seem to get the query to first see who is following Gavin and then see if they are online and return those users whom are online.

Comment: @marcinn actually there are some things that resemble RESTful stuff for example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search.html

it uses curl -GET request.  If I'm not mistaken the key word "GET" is from RESTful

The definition of RESTful uses verbiage such as GET, POST, PUT, etc.  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

So in fact it is similar to RESTful.

Comment: @marcinn furthermore it uses other RESTful verbiage such as PUT in this example you can update your data.  Again, very similar to RESTful https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/_modifying_your_data.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found a better solution (or maybe not).  First you query the database for users whom are following a user.

From this list you send another query

```
{
"query":{

    "filtered":{
        "query":{
            "match_all":{}
        },
        "filter":{
            "bool":{
                "must":{
                    "terms":{
                        "username":["username1"]
                    }
                },
                "must_not":{
                    "terms":{
                        "online":["true"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This works however the username cannot be mixed with capitols.  I don't know if this is an indexing issue on my part or terms have to be very specific.  The solution I'm using on the client side is to lowercase the search terms before I submit them. It's crude and hacky but it works for now.

Issues that I may run into:

1. If a user has millions of followers pulling all that data from the
   database will make the client sluggish.

   - a possible solution to this is to paginate the following results and run the query for every 20 returned results.

I'll continue to revise the answer as I develop / learn better query methods.

Comment: Without providing your mappings it's difficult to tell but I think your lower case issue is being caused by you having a lowercase analyzer being applied to the field but not the search. You can learn more about analyzers and how to set the default index and search analyzers at http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Comment: The default analyser splits on whitespace and converts to lowercase. If you are wanting to do exact matches (and not partial matches) then you'll need to set your mapping to index = not_analyzed. See the mapping section here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: Yes I saw that and I have since enabled it.  It stumped me for a bit but I eventually figured it out.  I must say the getting started tutorial leaves much to be desired.